# My friend and I are receiving packets from a server in UDP, I am able to receive them but he can't

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp

My friend and I are writing a game in sfml. We wrote both the client and the server in C++. The library we used to handle the networking is SFML. The clients send block update packets to the server and the server sends them to all connected players. This works fine, both my friend and I are able to receive the TCP packets. The problem is with the UDP player position packets. The server receives a UDP packet containing the players x y z (position coordinates) and pitch and yaw(direction the player is looking). Then it sends that information to all other connected clients.(This happens 10 times per second) We put a simple printf() statement to detect whether my friend is even receiving the udp packets but it turns out he was not. And I am obviously receiving the UDP packets since it I am able to see his position.

We thought this was because the server is sending UDP packets to the clients' router's IP but the packet does not contain the local ip of the computer the packet is meant for. Later, we learned that when the server sends a packet to the router, the packet gets sent containing a public ip address and a public port, the router then maps that port to a local ip address and a local port. However this is called port forwarding and requires the routers to be configured.

We just want to know why isn't this a problem with TCP connections?
Why am I able to receive the UDP packets without port forwarding?
Is port forwarding necessary for UDP communication?

Answer (score 4):

> We just want to know why isn't this a problem with TCP connections?

Because a connection is bidirectional.

> Why am I able to receive the UDP packets without port forwarding?

There could be a lot of possibilities and there's no way we can know without looking much more closely. Here are a few possibilities:

1. You aren't behind a router that's doing NAT.
2. The router that does NAT for you isn't between your client and the server.
3. Your client sent a UDP datagram to the server and your router recognizes the response UDP datagram as a reply to that, creating the effect of having a "UDP connection".
4. Your client uses UPnP and your router supports UPnP to get port forwarding without special effort.
5. The server sets the source and destination UDP ports incorrectly and, by luck, it still works in your case. For example, the source and destination ports might happen to be the same or your router's NAT is especially permissive.
6. The server sets its source IP address incorrectly and this just happens to work in your case either because your router's NAT is more permissive or because the IP address you send to and the IP address the server sends from happen to be the same in your case.
7. You send a UDP datagram to the server and your friend didn't, thus your datagrams are seen as replies and your friend's aren't.

You can narrow things down if you can dump packets at the server. Seeing a UDP datagram from your friend as seen by the server followed by a UDP datagram from the server to your friend would help narrow things down a lot.

> Is port forwarding necessary for UDP communication?

Generally no. If the client sends the first UDP datagram and the server correctly swaps the source and destination ports and the source and destination IP addresses, the UDP reply datagram will usually work.

The client must send UDP to the server *first*. The server must ensure that the UDP datagram is seen as a reply. That means the server looks at the UDP datagrams it gets from the client and ensures that it responds *from* the port the client sent UDP *to* and *to* the port the client sent UDP *from*. Similarly, it must send to the IP address the client sent *from* and send *from* the IP address the client send *to*.

Generally, servers offer TCP fallback or some other form of NAT penetration in case things don't "just work".